# Variable in my view wont reflect value from observable

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, observable

I've checked out a lot of examples on SO on how to solve this issue but none of the solutions are working for me.  I have a class running a process recursively 20 times and I'm keeping track of the process in an observable.  I want to use those values to create a progress bar on the view.

I know the observable is working because if I subscribe directly in my component and console.log the numbers they are appearing in 20 increments as expected.

No matter what I do I'm only seeing the initial value and the final value in my view.  I am not able to see the progress.

Any advice here?

```
// my scheduler class
private calendarPercent = new Subject()
private finishedCalendarMax = 20
private finishedCalendarCount = 0

// this stuff is called recursively until we hit our finishedCalendarMax
this.finishedCalendarCount++
this.calendarPercent.next(this.finishedCalendarCount / this.finishedCalendarMax)

// get my observable
getFinishedCalendarPercent() {
    return this.calendarPercent
}


// in app.component.ts i create my scheduler class
public scheduler = new Scheduler()


// in app.component.html
{{ scheduler.getFinishedCalendarPercent()  | async }}
```

Comment: What happens if you directly subscribe, but instead of using `console.log`, update a variable instead, and then use that variable inside your HTML instead of relying on the async pipe?

Comment: If your Subject has finished emitting values by the time the template renders, then the `async` pipe will never hear any events. You may be better off using a `BehaviorSubject` instead

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz showing the problem?

Comment: @kshetline the same thing. Only see first and final value

Comment: @user184994 I've tried behaviorsubject. It acts the same way

Comment: As suggested then, can you please create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @user184994 I'm not sure how to set those up.. but I'll try

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-dumb-schedule
when you hit the generate button you'll see the number pop up below after it finishes generating a calendar.  look in the console to see "the number i want" being printed from my observable within app.component.ts.  I need that decimal value  to update live within my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `this.generateCalendar` recursively, simply wrap it in a `setTimeout`, like so:

```
setTimeout(() => this.generateCalendar(), 0)
```

With the timeout set to 0, this moves the next calculation to the end of the execution queue, which gives the UI a chance to render the changes.

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-dumb-schedule-a2sa8b?file=src/app/scheduler.ts)**

Comment: thanks for the help! burnt way too much time on this